# Make paths of ID's as page paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created html page with a lot of divs:

```
<div id="div1">
   <!-- Some code -->
</div>

<div id="div2">
   <!-- Some code -->
</div>

<div id="div3">
   <!-- Some code -->
</div>
```

There are a lot of `<a>` tags where `href` has ids of these `<div>s`, when I click to links, it shows me `<div>` and in my browser address path it shows me this:

```
index.html#div1
```

I want it to show in my bowsers address path like this:

```
index.html/div1
```

How it is possible?

**==========UPDATE==========**

I have searched from internet and wrote this code:

```
    $('ul.nav li a').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();


            var $this = $(this);

            var $href = $this.attr('href');

            window.history.pushState({}, '', $href);

        });
```

I checked the value of my clicked `href` and it gave me something like this:

```
http://path/index.html#div1
```

I have tried to edit it as string, by replacing `#` with `/`,  and place it on `windows.history.pushState` but now it gives to me `SecurityError`.

Answer (score 1):

put this in your .httacces file :

```
RewriteEngine On

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^index\.html/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.html#$1 [L]
```

Comment: I don't have any httaccess file. I am simply using `file:///` path

Comment: you need a apache server,php,mod_rewrite enabled in php

Comment: Is it possible to just add something to javascript or edit css to make addresses of hashes like addresses of pages?

Comment: I have added your code in my `htaccess` file. Now when I click on links, url addres does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>   
        <rule patternSyntax="ExactMatch" name="div1">
          <match url="index.html/div1" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html#div1" />
        </rule>
        <rule patternSyntax="ExactMatch" name="div2">
          <match url="index.html/div2" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html#div2" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because hash part isn't send to server

Comment: I dont have any web.config files or .httaccess files.

Comment: you can create .httaccess files if you have mod_rewrite enabled in php ini configuration file

Comment: @madalinivascu But hash isn't send to server and anyway clicking anchor with internal link set (using hash) doesn't request the server. My bet is that OP should look at window history API to replace current URL client side. But i could be completly wrong, for sure... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mr. D is it possible for you to use JavaScript ? It can be used without server. The angularjs $route service has these features. 
For you to get started you could refer to the tutorial hosted for routing in https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 and a live demo of the same is in - http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/#/phones.

However, you would have noticed the # symbol in the Url, I am still figuring out if that could be removed to get you exactly what you want. If anyone in the forum could help Mr. D would get what is required.